# Pandas Dates CSV read, reads dates differntlly

Tags: pandas, csv, date, format

I have a dataframe where the date column is in MM/DD/YY,mm/dd/yy.

Example of last 5 rows from the CSV file:(MM/DD/YYYY)

01/08/2018
01/05/2018
01/04/2018
01/03/2018
01/02/2018

but panda reads some of the dates (not all) as follows:YYYY-DD-MM (after using:
df['Trade Date']= pd.to_datetime(df['Trade Date'],dayfirst=True)

2018-08-01
2018-05-01
2018-04-01
2018-03-01
2018-02-01

I want all the dates in DD-MM-YYYY format. Whats going on and how can I solve this.

Thanks for any help.

Tried several methods but nothing seems to work. Tried parsing, tried format nothing works

Comment: Can you share what you tried so far ?

Comment: I have resolved the issue. Due to the different date formats in the CSV month was being converted to day. I downloaded the same files in .xls format and the issue was resolved. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Trade Date': ['01/08/2018', '01/05/2018', '01/04/2018', '01/03/2018', '01/02/2018']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print("Original DataFrame:")
print(df)

df['Trade Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Trade Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y')

df['Trade Date'] = df['Trade Date'].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')

print("\nDataFrame after reformatting:")
print(df)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. All this don't work. It seems that the date column has text date as well as excel dates in the CSV file. Thats why pandas is giving me the mentioned dates. Either I have to convert the text date manually in the CSV or need to find a way to convert it in pandas. Ideas are welcome

Comment: @ImtiazSattar can you share the csv file containing only the date ? I understand you may work on sensitive data. So help us so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

Your `dayfirst=True` argument can lead to wrong formats within ambiguous date formats (for example, finnish vs swedish timeformats which have completely different structures).

You can extract the dateformat which your csv files uses by this command:

```
df['Trade Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Trade Date'], format='%m-%d-%Y')
```

which will make sure the date is converted to a format such as `MM/DD/YYYY`.

You can freely customize the `format`.

Now, to your original question to get the date in the following format: `DD-MM-YYYY`, you can use

```
df['Trade Date'] = df['Trade Date'].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

This way, you are specifying the exact format you want pandas to interpret the dates in.